# Unidentified Error in Program: Unfriendly Numbers

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

There is a problem in Interview Street challange. Maybe the most easiest of all challenges. "Unfriendly Numbers", is the name and question goes like this.

There is one friendly number and N unfriendly numbers. We want to find how many numbers are there which exactly divide the friendly number, but does not divide any of the unfriendly numbers.

Input Format:
The first line of input contains two numbers N and K seperated by spaces. N is the number of unfriendly numbers, K is the friendly number.
The second line of input contains N space separated unfriendly numbers.

Output Format:
Output the answer in a single line.

I did a PHP programming like this:

```
<?php
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$input = fgets($handle);
$num_unfriendly_number=substr($input,0,1);
$friendly_number=substr($input,2,1);
$input2=fgets($handle);
for($i=0;$i<=($num_unfriendly_number); $i=$i+2){
    $unfriendly_numbers[$i]=substr($input2,$i,1);

}
//truncates additional input

//now getting divisiors of given friendly numbers

$check_num=1;
//one is always a divisor of any number
$divisior[0]=1;
$arrayindex=1;
for($check_num; $check_num<=$friendly_number; $check_num++){

    $hold_var=$friendly_number%$check_num;
    if($hold_var==0){
        $divisor[$arrayindex]=$check_num;
        $arrayindex++;
    }

}
$index=0;
foreach($divisor as $test_div){
    $output=true;
    foreach($unfriendly_numbers as $test_unfrnd){
        if($test_unfrnd%$test_div){
            $output=false;
        }
    }
    if ($output){
        $outputarray[$index]=$test_div;
        $index++; //edited afterwards after @Boris's suggestion but didn't work :(
    }
}
$num_of_output=count($outputarray);
define('STDOUT',fopen("php://stout","r"));  
fwrite(STDOUT,$num_of_output);
?>
```

The above programme worked fine for 2 testcases but did not applied for other tests. I did some research but did not found any errors. Any helps please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like codereview would be a better fit for this.

Comment: It would be better if you describe the algorithm used.

Comment: @PriyankBhatnagar I think brute force is the best description. Maybe I can help here: he finds all the divisors of the friendly number and then filters out all of the divisors that divide any of the unfriendly numbers.

Comment: @bdares Sorry, but what's codereview! A web-forum?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev. Yeah, you are rite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all I would like to mention that I do not know php. However, I think this is simple enough I can try to help.

Several errors I see:

```
for($i=0;$i<=($num_unfriendly_number); $i=$i+2){
    $unfriendly_numbers[$i]=substr($input2,$i,1);
}
```

Here you use `substr($input2,$i,1);`, this however assumes all your unfriendly numbers are digits, which might not always be the case. Better use the split function in php. Replace the whole while with the following:

```
$unfriendly_numbers = explode(" ", $input2);
```

After that:

```
$index=0;
foreach($divisor as $test_div){
    $output=true;
    foreach($unfriendly_numbers as $test_unfrnd){
        if($test_unfrnd%$test_div){
            $output=false;
        }
    }
    if ($output){
        $outputarray[$index]=$test_div;
    }
}
```

Here you never increase the `$index` variable. Isn't this meaning that you will override the divisors one with other? USe the operator `[]=`. It appends to an array in php:

```
 if ($output){
     $outputarray []= $test_div;
 }
```

**EDIT** One more error I see is that you count on the friendly number to be a digit too. You can fix this too:

```
$friendly_number=substr($input,2,1);
```

->

```
$friendly_number=explode(" ", $input)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the error-pointing. but that didn't help either. What i am trying to do is get number or divisor which exactly divides the friendly number but does not divide any of the unfriendly number.

Comment: @cipher Yes, and you seem to be doing exactly that. Can you be more specific as of what does not work. I am just eye-scanning the code and it might be that I do not find all the errors.

Comment: The programme just returns 1 as the output. Syntax is right and i am checking out for the semantics. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your help. I guess, some checking will result in error_free programme

Comment: @cipher did you apply the corrections I suggested? The second suggestion is related to your program always returning 1.

Comment: Yap, I applied that and used [] hoping it appends to the query. I'll now try increasing the $index and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem I can't understand why this code can't finish in less than 16 seconds!
I would like to hear your tricks

`a = raw_input()`# this will read this line: 8 16
`b = raw_input()`# this will read this line: 2 5 7 4 3 8 3 18

```
al = a.split()

bl = b.split()

blint = []

fn = int(al[1])
fnlist = [fn]
```

`half_fn = fn / 2` # only I go to half the number to save some time

```
k = 1

while k <= half_fn:
    if fn % k == 0:
        fnlist.append(k)
    k += 1

plist = []
for j in bl:
    blint.append(int(j)) # here I changed the bl list elements which are string to int

for i in fnlist:
    for j in blint: #I have the int elements so I don't need every time bring the string and change it to int
        if j % i == 0:
            plist.append(i)
            break
counter = len(fnlist) - len(plist)
print counter
```